# Oracle to Postgresql Query Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Actually I have some oracle query which is about oracle database default tables. That is working  in the oracle. Now I want to execute those queries in my postgresql database. What is the correct way to do that....?

For some of the queries I am able to convert from oracle to postgresql as follows.

```
example 1: 

Oracle : Select * from dba_users  ; 
Equal Posgresql query is : select * from pg_users ; 

example 2: 
oracle : select * from dba_role ; 
Equal Postgrsql query is : select * from pg_roles
```

Like this I need to convert many queries which should work in postgres. 
Is there any tool to convert ...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, to my knowledge, a one-stop tool that will fix all your problems, but the information at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Oracle should help you to plough through it manually.